# Vector2.MoveTowards not moving my object in a coroutine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a Hookshot class that contains a public coroutine I'm calling when the object it's attached to (the hookshot) is instantiated in another script.  The goal is for the coroutine CastHookshot to move the object out a set distance, then start the ReturnHookshot coroutine to move it back to the player.  A smooth back and forth motion.  There are going to be additional design choices that prohibit me from using Mathf.PingPong or Mathf.Sin for this, so it needs to be two coroutines.  Regardless, for some reason the object isn't moving at all and I can't figure out why. I tested with Debug.Log and know that the coroutines are being hit.  The castDistance being passed in is 50 so the distance conditional for the loop shouldn't be an issue either.

```c#
public class Hookshot : MonoBehaviour
{

    private Vector2 playerPos;
    private readonly float hookshotCastTime = 0.2f;
    private readonly float hookshotReturnSpeed = 4f;
    private readonly float hookshotDistanceBuffer = 0.2f;

    public IEnumerator CastHookshot(float castDistance, Vector2 aimDir)
    {
        playerPos = gameObject.transform.position;
        Vector2 target = playerPos + (castDistance * aimDir);
        float speed = castDistance / hookshotCastTime * Time.deltaTime;
        while (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, target) > hookshotDistanceBuffer)
        {
            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(playerPos, target, speed);
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        }
        transform.position = target;
        StartCoroutine(ReturnHookshot());
    }

    public IEnumerator ReturnHookshot()
    {
        Vector2 pos = gameObject.transform.position;
        while (Vector2.Distance(pos, playerPos) > hookshotDistanceBuffer)
        {
            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(pos, playerPos, hookshotReturnSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is probably in the line

```c#
transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(playerPos, target, speed);
```

you never update the `playerPos` value so [`MoveTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.MoveTowards.html)

> Moves a point `current` towards `target`.

every frame returns exactly the same value since you tell it to always start from the same position and also use a fix calculated distance.

Also the multiplication by `Time.deltaTime` should be done every frame so you actually use the correct value for each frame instead of calculating it only with the value of the very first frame.

---

Note that [`Vector3`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html) and [`Vector2`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.html) are no `class` but `struct` and thereby **value** type and **NOT** a **reference** type. It seems like you expected them to be reference types thus `pos` and `playerPos` would get updated if you change the `transform.position` but that is **not** the case!

You would rather want to change it to

```c#
float speed = castDistance / hookshotCastTime;

...

transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target, speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

And the same also in the second routine. Especially the loop condition here will never return since `pos` is never updated! So change it to

```c#
while (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, playerPos) > hookshotDistanceBuffer)
{
    transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, playerPos, hookshotReturnSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: Ahh thank you for the explanation that makes a lot of sense! I'll make the changes when I get home today

Comment: This is the right answer.  I'll update the question to the CORRECT code so others can learn from it.

Comment: @dulong No please don't! How should others learn from it if nobody can see how the code looked before/what the question was about? ;)